# Multiple subprojects in Projects

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I have some API/Classes in my project and I want to add two sub projects (iPad/iPhone) such that those sub projects only implement the UI and application delegates stuff and only *reference* to my existing API/Classes. what's the best way to do this?

Thanks.